# Get interface that can have multiple query responses in GraphQL

Tags: javascript, graphql

Currently in my GraphQL query, i can receive a single array response. But my response can be multiple arrays and there can be null in between of the response too depending on the input. Currenly if i have two inputs and suppose i'm getting an array for the first input and error for the second, it will throw an error. I need to fix that by showing null if error and returning the array if success. Here's what i have right now:

```js
export const LookupUsers = gql`
  query {
    lookupUsers(ethAddresses: ["0x433232bC8C604d0308B71Defdgd1Da86"]) {
      ...User
    }
  }

  fragment Identifiable on Node {
    __typename
    id
  }

  fragment User on User {
    ...Identifiable
    ethAddress
    firstName
    lastName
  }
`;

export interface Result {
  readonly user:  null | Array<null | User> ;
  readonly lookupUsers: Array<null | LookupUsersType>;
}

export interface LookupPayload {
  readonly payload: Array<string>;
}

export interface User extends Identifiable {
  readonly ethAddress: string;
  readonly emailAddress?: string;
  readonly firstName?: string;
  readonly lastName?: string;
}

export interface LookupUsersType extends Identifiable {
  readonly ethAddress: string;
  readonly emailAddress: string;
  readonly firstName?: string;
  readonly lastName?: string;
}
export interface Identifiable {
  readonly __typename: string;
  readonly id: string;
}
```

Where am i going wrong with this ?

Comment: why are you creating types manually? Try to use `https://www.the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen`